# ratio of the length of right triangle are identical proof

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, angle

If a right triangle has an angle theta, the length of the opposite x divided by the length of adjacent y is always equal when x and y is real positive number, and it is relative to angle theta. how to prove this proposition.

Comment: Corresponding sides of similar triangles are proportional.

Answer (score 1):

Let in $\Delta ABC$ we have $\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle A=\theta.$

Let $D$ and $E$  be placed on the rays $AC$ and $AB$ respectively such that $\measuredangle ADE=90^{\circ}.$

Thus, $CB||DE$ and we obtain $\Delta ACB\sim\Delta ADE,$ which gives
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{CB}{AC}=\frac{DE}{AD},$$ which says that $\frac{x}{y}$ depend on $\measuredangle A$ only.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one or two theorems stating that if two triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ are similar so that $\angle A \cong D$ and $\angle B \cong E$ and $\angle C \cong F$ then

1) and the proportion of any two corresponding sides are equal to the porportion of any other two corresponding sides.  That is:

$\frac {AB}{DE} = \frac {BC}{EF} = \frac {AC}{DF}$.

and 2)

any the proportions of any two sides of one triangle will be the same as the proportions of the corresponding sides of the other triangle.  That is:

$\frac {AB}{BC} = \frac {DE}{EF}$ and $\frac {AB}{AC} = \frac {DE}{DF}$ and $\frac {BC}{AC} = \frac {EF}{DF}$ etc.

We can prove number 2) from number 1) via the following.

Let $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DEF$

Then $\frac {AB}{DE} = \frac {BC}{EF}$ so

$AB =\frac {BC\cdot DE}{EF}$ and

$\frac {AB}{BC} = \frac {DE}{EF}$.

We can do this for all sides.

.....

And we know if we have two triangles are such that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ are such that $m\angle A = m\angle D=\theta$ and $m\angle B = m\angle E =90^\circ$ then we know $m\angle C = m\angle F = 90 -\theta$.

So the triangles are similar and the theorem 2) applies.

If the opposite angle of $BC = x$ and $AB = y$ and $EF = x'$ and $DE = y'$, then we have $\frac x{x'} = \frac y{y'}$ and by simple algebra $\frac xy = \frac {x'}{y'}$.

Comment: How to prove the theorem one

Comment: It depends on your text.  It's often a definition or an axiom.  If you take the area formula for granted it follows imediately.  Anyway, what does your *text* say.  It is in there somewhere.

Comment: I do not have one, I just curious while using trigonometry function

Comment: Well, if you are studying trigonometry, these facts about similar triangles are considered so very basic and the entire premise that allows trigonometry to exist.  The ratio you describe is just the tangent function.

Comment: It Euclid's Element Book VI, Proposition 4 https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI4.html  It is proved by constructing parallel lines and using the Area formulas (which are a definition, I think).  But nearly every elementary introduction takes this as a god given fact almost a definition.

Comment: If you accept that the definition of area is half base times height, then figures (rectangles, triangles, and parallegrams) would follow that proportional sides if and only if equal angles.